# Incorrect display text in TextView via Html.fromHtml()

Tags: android, html, parsing, textview

in my app i have string (for example) :

`String s = "log<small><sub>(log<small><sub>(log<small><sub>3<small><sup>2</sup></small></sub></small>(40))</sub></small>(39!))</sub></small>(40!)"`.

It's a mathematical expression, as you see. And when i do `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s))` text in `TextView` incorrect displayed (see on logarithm base 3^2):

[image: incorrect]

but in browser this `String` displayed correct (try it if you want):
[image]

WHY?

Comment: I think the problem should be somewhere in your xml file...can u post the snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i guessed earlier, the problem was in xml file...I copied your text but it shows the error like you said. But, then I changed the `layout_width` to `fill_parent`

and it is now fine...